# Picking image from server: FileField_Sources not working

Tags: files, media

I currently have some nodes that use images.
Problem is: every time I want to choose an image, I have to upload it again.
It would be much better if I could just use a path picker, which could show which images are already uploaded.

This way I could upload the images through FTP and would make me able to give the authors only the rights to choose an already existing image, to be safe with author rights of the pictures.

I found that FileField_Sources can give the file picker, yet still have the upload function as well, ok fair enough, it's just a matter of telling the authors not to use the upload function.

Problem is, it doesn't work.

I installed the following modules:

1. FileField Sources
2. IMCE
3. IMCE for FileField

However, my original file upload is still unchanged
[image]

And I also don't have any new options to choose from in my content types manage fields part.

PS: Yes I activated all the modules in the modules page.

PS2: I also tried to use imagepicker as a module, but this adds a picture in the body. This is NOT what I want, I need the image to come into an image field.

---

A secondary question as well:
I want to put the copyights of the pictures on the site as well: preferably a bar coming over the bottom of the picture when you hover it, but a text below is also good enough.
If anyone knows a module for this or anything like that, it would very much be appreciated. If not I will just add an extra text field "copyrights" that I will just show below the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer myself.

If anyone else would come into the need for something like this:

1. Download the 3 modules that I had typed in my question
2. Go to the Manage fields of your content type & click edit next to the Field
3. Scroll down and click Allow users to select files from IMCE File Browser for this field.

I forgot 2 & 3 :)

I do have to say that it's not 100% what I wanted, as I have different image fields in different nodes, and it only finds the image fields of the nodes that it's in. But I guess I should have used the references instead to make that work...

If anyone still has an answer for my secondary question, it would be much appreciated though, but I'll try to fix that myself tomorrow.